# Convert Owl class to java class or xml

Tags: java, xml, xsd, ontology, owl

I am wondering if there are any tools that can convert an owl ontology xml schema or an xml document. Or is there any way to generate a java class for a given owl class.

Lets say I have owl class document, with two datatype properties hasAuthor and hasName. Can I create java class for this owl class. ?

the java class should be something like this

```
public class document {

    string hasAuthor;
    string hasName;

}
```

Is there any api which supports this conversion.

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: Lion thanks for your comment. I was not much worried about syntax error here :)

Comment: *"I was not much worried about syntax error here"*  So start worrying about it.  Programming is a precise business, and here you are trying to communicate a problem to an international audience.  When it comes too code 'near enough is not good enough'.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson Thanks for your comment. I will make sure I will not have not these errors in when posting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior using JAXB. Here is the main article for JAXB API:

- [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

The process to create an instance object from a XML file is called Unmarshalling. Here is another good tutorial on this matter:

- [JAXB Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)

Comment: is this JAXB to convert an Owl class into a java class ? or converting an owl ontology to xsd ?

Comment: @Priyatham51 oh sorry, I misunderstood the question at all. Still, JAXB API is suited to convert XML document to Java classes instances and viceversa.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza I am already using castor for this. NOw I am looking for something that can create a java class from OWL CLass. OR something to convert an OWL Ontology Document to xml or XSD.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across http://wiki.yoshtec.com/jaob which seems to be project for mapping OWL definitions into java classes.